# How to generate delegate constructors in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, delegates, code-generation

I want to extend some class which is final, like [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). So, I need to use composition

```
public class MyScanner  {

    private final Scanner delegate;

}
```

now, `Scanner` has 10 constructors.

How can I delegate all of them fast in Eclipse?

`Generate Delegate Methods` function does not suggest to delegate constructors for some (unknown to me) reason.